# CSS Multi DIV Layout Not Expanding Vertically

Tags: css, html

I've been reading through SO most of the morning and the fixes I've tried don't seem to yield any different result then the problem I'm having. Instead of the page dynamically expanding based on the content of the main div that holds the page data, the div just disappears behind the footer portions.

Here's the HTML layout

```
<div id="fp_wrapper">
  <div id="fp_top_bar">
    <!-- content here -->
  </div>
  <div id="fp_marquee">
    <div id="fp_logo_wrapper_a">
      <!-- content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="fp_logo_wrapper_b">
      <!-- content here -->
    </div>
    <div id="fp_page_content">
      <!-- This is the DIV that is not forcing the expansion of the page
           It just expands below the social bar and footer below
      -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="fp_social_bar">
  <!-- content here -->
</div>
<div id="fp_footer">
  <!-- content here -->
  <span id="fp_footer_copyright"></span>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS. From what I've ready it seems to be an issue that a floating DIV could be causing this but I've tried every combination of adding clear:both to multiple different divs and even tried the :before and :after psuedo classes.

```
html, body{height:100%;margin:0;font-family:Arial, Verdana Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color:#000;background:url("/images/bgrnd_landing3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;}

#fp_wrapper{height:100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:-78px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);behavior:url("https://domain-omitted/css/pie/PIE.htc");overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;}

#fp_top_bar{clear:both;height:40px;margin:auto;padding-top:5px;padding-right:10px;font-family:inherit;font-size:16px;color:#fff;text-align:right;}
#fp_top_bar a, #fp_top_bar a:hover, #fp_top_bar a:visited, #fp_top_bar a:active{text-decoration:none;color:#fff;padding-right:10px}
#fp_top_bar a:hover{color:#1468b3}
#fp_top_bar img{vertical-align:middle;}

#fp_marquee{clear:both;width:100%;height:auto;font-family:inherit;text-align:left;overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;padding-left:25px}

#fp_logo_wrapper_a{float:left;height:150px;width:48%;overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;color:#fff;}
#fp_logo_wrapper_b{float:right;height:150px;width:48%;overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;color:#fff;}

#fp_page_content{clear:both;height:auto;width:75%;margin:auto;font-family:inherit;background:rgba(20, 104, 179, 0.4);border:2px solid #fff;color:#fff;padding-left:10px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;padding-top:10px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;behavior:url("https://domain-omitted/css/pie/PIE.htc");}

#fp_social_bar{clear:both;height:48px;}
#fp_social_bar img{padding-right:10px;opacity:0.8;filter:alpha(opacity=80);}
#fp_social_bar img:hover{opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=100);}

#fp_footer{clear:both;font-family:inherit;font-size:11px;height:30px;line-height:30px;margin:auto;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);color:#fff;text-align:middle;}
#fp_footer a, #fp_footer a:hover, #fp_footer a:visited, #fp_footer a:active{text-decoration:none;color:#fff;padding-left:10px}
#fp_footer a:hover{color:#1468b3}

#fp_footer_copyright{float:right;padding-right:10px;
```

**EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle**

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ5FS/)

**UPDATE**
Zack's help below adds the scrollbar I was wanting but it doesn't automatically expand the DIV in the way I was wanting. The footer should be pushed down below the content, not remain in place and have the content scroll up behind it.

Comment: Can you please move this to a JS Fiddle? It's much easier for us to give you an answer while working with live code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the `margin-bottom: -78px` in the `#fp-wrapper` selector.

I did some updating to the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ5FS/12/)

remove the `overflow: hidden;` on the wrapper and set this to the footer div:

```
position:fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks Zach! I was able to finish tweaking it after I got the mess sorted out.

Comment: Also note there are errors in your CSS. `text-align: middle` isn't a valid rule. It should be `text-align: center` @rsmith84

Comment: I just realized that it allows me to scroll but I need the div to auto expand the entire page, not just scroll what's behind the footer. The footer should remain pinned to the bottom but if the content in the main page div is large enough, it should just push the footer down and allow the user to scroll through all the content and when they reach the end, then they will see the footer.